# How do i find all the students that have got more than 70 in any subjects?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

i have a my sql table having 5 students and each gives 5 exams.

i need to get all the students that have got more than 70 marks in any subject with the name of the subject.

[image]

the table looks like this and i am new to mysql so i am not able to find the correct query.

please help !

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide an attempt so people can help you learn, rather than feed you an answer. Please read [ask] Also, you are more likely to be assisted if you place the text in the question rather than linking to an image.

Comment: This is a very poor data model.  The subjects should each be in separate rows rather than separate columns.  I would suggest you put your efforts to fixing the data model.

Comment: Consider providing example data and sample output as *text* not as a screen shot image https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question  It might be super easy for you to create a screenshot, but it makes it a lot harder for anyone that might want to help you. Even better, consider setting up a demonstration, like on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://dbfiddle.com/ with table definition and example data.

Comment: Also, "I am not able to find the correct query" is a *story*, not a question. We will note that a SQL query typically starts with SELECT and includes a FROM clause with a table name. I apologize if this is overly obvious, but there doesn't appear to be any attempt at any query shown in the question. We will also note that the denormalize structure of the data will make queries much more complex than the would be if the data were in a more normalized form.

Comment: [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73566) can find some suggestion to post sql data

Comment: i am sorry if i asked question poorly  . also i just started SQL and ran into problems that is why asked it in a form of question answer. i know it is a very poor data model but i am given a project and i tried to get a code that produces an output like i wanted but i found none and thus i asked .

Answer (score 1):

In your case according to your database model I'd recommend making a query for each subject - 5 in total.

```
SELECT "enroll_no" FROM "tablename" WHERE "sub1_marks" > 70
```

and respectively do this for the other columns.

Replace "tablename" with the name of your table.

Each call will return a list of the enroll_no entries for where the number in the column you specified is greater than 70.

This is not very performant and you should change your model to have each exam on a separate row instead for a query like this.

Comment: thank you for answering. but by using this query 5 times and running it again and again i am getting 5 different tables showing output of all these queries only when i run anyone. for example if i run 'sub1_marks' > 70 then i am only getting those students that got more than 70 in subject 1 and so on . isn't there any way to get all these ouput in a single table ?

Comment: you can combine the WHERE clause with OR. E.g.:
SELECT "enroll_no" FROM "tablename" WHERE "sub1_marks" > 70 OR "sub2_marks" > 70 OR "sub3_marks" > 70 OR "sub4_marks" > 70 OR "sub5_marks" > 70
What you won't get is the info which of the 5 columns actually had values greater than 70.
And also needless to say that this is not very performant on larger tables.